# Passing a struct to a function when it takes an interface?

Tags: go

I have the code below which is from Go by Example. I understand everything except for one key part: if measure takes in something that is of type geometry, how is it that I am able to create a rect and pass that in?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type geometry interface {
    area() float64
}

type rect struct {
    width, height float64
}

func main() {
    r := rect{width: 10, height: 10}
    measure(r)
}

func measure(g geometry) {
    fmt.Println(g)
    fmt.Println(g.area())
}

func (r rect) area() float64 {
    return r.width * r.height
}
```

Comment: `rect` struct implements `geometry` interface so you can pass it in `measure` func.

what's the question?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `rect` implements `geometry`. All it means to implement an interface in Go is that the type implements its methods. Since `rect` has an `area` method, it satisfies the interface `geometry` as that is the only requirement.

Comment: Ahh ok this makes sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `rect` struct implements the `geometry` interface. You can confirm this using `fmt.Printf`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type geometry interface{ area() float64 }
type rect struct{ width, height float64 }

func (r rect) area() float64 { return r.width * r.height }

func measure(g geometry) {
    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", g, g)               //main.rect {10 10}
    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", g.area(), g.area()) //float64 100
}

func main() {
    r := rect{width: 10, height: 10}
    measure(r)
}
```

The example might also be more readable without an interface. See https://play.golang.org/p/0vpRU2Do4eA.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how would you implement the `area` which is defined in the interface? You would need method? A method needs a receiver. How do you define a receiver? A `struct`. Here `rect` completes the interface. So, `measure` implements `geometry` on `rect`. Thats why it accepts `rect` as a parameter.